# Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'x' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't understand why I'm getting `Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'x' not found` from the following code.

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 7:9) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = 7,
           label = paste("sd(x) =", sd(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `.data`

```
 data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 7:9) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate("text", x = 1, y = 7,
           label = paste("sd(x) =", sd(.data[["x"]])))
```

The issue with above method is that as we already give the location, the value extracted for 'x' column in that location is just a single value and thus `sd` on a single value returns `NA`.  If we need the `sd` on the whole dataset, we may need a temporary object created

```
data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 7:9) -> tmp;
  ggplot(tmp, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() + 
    annotate("text", x = 1, y = 7, 
        label = paste('sd(x) = ', sd(tmp[['x']])))
```

Comment: Your last code block seems to be missing a third closing parenthesis; however, upon editing your answer, I see you've included one.

Comment: @NickVence thanks.  I updated.  I think I may have copied incorrectly from the console